# Can't add IdentityServer4 NuGet package to ASP.NET Core project properly and VS Code is not showing intellisense

Tags: c#, nuget, asp.net-core-2.0, identityserver4, dotnet-cli

I've added IdentityServer4 NuGet package to ASP.NET core project using dotnet cli. Then written the  following code on `Startup` class.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {           
        services.AddIdentityServer()
            .AddInMemoryClients(new Client[] 
                { 
                    new Client
                    { 
                        ClientId = "react client", 
                        ClientName = "React Client",
                        AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Implicit,
                        RedirectUrls = {"http://localhost:51009/"},
                        AllowedScopes = { "openid"}
                    }
                });            
        services.AddMvc();
    }
```

Then when I build the project it shows error: `The type or namespace name 'Client' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Moreover VS Code doesn't show any suggestion for IdentityServer related code.

And when I search IdentityServer4 on NuGet website it shows result like following:
[image: Search result on NuGet website]

And when I search IdentityServer4 on Visual Studio 2017 it shows result like following:
[image: Search result on Visual Studio 2017]

Comment: Have you included the using-statement to IdentityServer4.Models?

Comment: Build error is gone after adding `IdentityServer4.Models`. But VS Code is still not showing any intellisense for IdentityServer4 related code.

Comment: Ok, great! Can I add that as an answer to this question? have you installed the c# extension to VS code which is needed for intellisense?

Comment: Yes and yes. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The IdentityServer4 Client class is located in the IdentityServer4.Models namespace which is included in the nuget-package.

Adding the using-statement where the model/models are needed should resolve the issue

```
using IdentityServer4.Models
```

Answer (score 0):

VS Code was not showing intellisense because of an OmniSharp bug. Solution to this problem is restarting OmniSharp.

`Ctrl` + `Shift` + `P` and then type `Restart OmniSharp`